# How to make so that when the display is reduced the text is fixed without going down HTML, CSS, ReactJS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to make it so that when I shrink the display, the text doesn't go outside the container.

ReactJS Code:

```
<div className="App">
 <header className="App-header">
        <Container fluid className='Header-text'>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              Автомобилната спедиция на "ДЪЛГЪЧЕВ ТРАНС ЕООД" е отдел с ключово значение за фирмата. Той е създаден с цел постигане на оптимални транспортни решения, предлагайки разнообразен автопарк, гъвкавост на възможностите за транспорт с фокус върху максималната удовлетвореност на нашите клиенти.

              Нашата приоритетна стратегическа цел е качество на най-високо ниво на предлаганите от нас услуги. Ние предлагаме възможността да отделите време за важните моменти в живота като оставите всичко в нашите ръце.
            </Col>
          </Row>

          <Row className='Second-row-header'>
            <Col>
              <Button variant="secondary">Запитване</Button> <Button variant="secondary">Контакти</Button> <Button variant="secondary">Още...</Button>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
</header>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(10, 10, 10);
}

    .App-header {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.Header-text{
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  opacity: 1.0;
  border-radius: 10px 15px 15px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-image: url(./Images/front.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Result:

- When the window is maximized
  [image: Before]
- When the window is minimized.
  [image: After]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
/* with scrollbar */
.Header-text Col {
  overflow: scroll; /* or auto */
}

/* no scrollbar, just hide the text */
.Header-text Col {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

And also you can use % in padding that will give your text more responsive feeling:

```
.Header-text {
  padding: 20px 8%; /* 8% padding to left and right */
}
```